# Linux mint freezes on second account login - unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at (null)

Tags: linux-mint, login, freeze

I have two accounts, `daniel` and `dn`. When I log in with `daniel` first, everything is okay. But I can't login with `dn`, it freezes. It's irrelevant if I log out `daniel` or try a parallel login. It's the same way round with the account `daniel` if I log in `dn` first.

The desktop is shown, without any folders and I can't move the mouse.

Some information about the system:

64 bit dual boot Mint 16 MATE / windows 8

Both Systems on the same SSD / Secondary HDD

Error message from `syslog`

```
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO rtkit-daemon[1843]: Successfully made thread 2507 of process 2507 (n/a) owned by '1001' high priority at nice level -11.
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO rtkit-daemon[1843]: Supervising 7 threads of 3 processes of 2 users.
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.630773] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at           (null)
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.630827] IP: [<ffffffffa01e0eb6>] nvc0_vm_map_sg+0x96/0x100 [nouveau]
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.630891] PGD 0 
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.630905] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP 
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.630927] Modules linked in: pci_stub vboxpci(OF) vboxnetadp(OF) vboxnetflt(OF) vboxdrv(OF) joydev(F) x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel(F) parport_pc(F) ppdev(F) kvm(F) crct10dif_pclmul(F) crc32_pclmul(F) ghash_clmulni_intel(F) cryptd(F) bnep rfcomm dm_multipath(F) scsi_dh(F) uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core videodev btusb arc4(F) bluetooth iwldvm mac80211 microcode(F) snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep(F) snd_pcm(F) psmouse(F) serio_raw(F) snd_page_alloc(F) snd_seq_midi(F) snd_seq_midi_event(F) iwlwifi snd_rawmidi(F) snd_seq(F) snd_seq_device(F) snd_timer(F) cfg80211 lpc_ich snd(F) mei_me mei soundcore(F) fujitsu_laptop mac_hid lp(F) parport(F) dm_mirror(F) dm_region_hash(F) dm_log(F) hid_generic usbhid hid nouveau i915 mxm_wmi wmi i2c_algo_bit ttm drm_kms_helper drm r8169 ahci(F) libahci(F) mii(F) video(F)
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.631442] CPU: 3 PID: 2281 Comm: Xorg Tainted: GF          O 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.631489] Hardware name: FUJITSU LIFEBOOK AH531/GFO/FJNBB10, BIOS 1.16 06/21/2011
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.631534] task: ffff8801fcacddc0 ti: ffff880230c4e000 task.ti: ffff880230c4e000
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.631578] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffa01e0eb6>]  [<ffffffffa01e0eb6>] nvc0_vm_map_sg+0x96/0x100 [nouveau]
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.631649] RSP: 0018:ffff880230c4f5f0  EFLAGS: 00010206
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.631679] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000005 RCX: 0000000500000000
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.631718] RDX: 000000000000041f RSI: 0000000000000003 RDI: ffff88022dc84e80
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.631758] RBP: ffff880230c4f640 R08: 0000000000000420 R09: 0000000000000000
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.631799] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000008000 R12: 0000000000001db0
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.631833] R13: ffff88022ec75240 R14: ffff88022dc84e80 R15: 0000000000000000
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.631870] FS:  00007f065be1d980(0000) GS:ffff88023fac0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.631917] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.631951] CR2: 0000000000000000 CR3: 000000022f4d7000 CR4: 00000000000407e0
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.631990] Stack:
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.632002]  ffff88020e237940 00001db40e237940 0000000000002100 0000000000000000
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.632048]  0000000500000000 0000000000000420 ffff88022e913d00 ffff88022ec75240
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.632091]  ffff88020e237940 ffff88020e237900 ffff880230c4f698 ffffffffa01dedcc
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.632136] Call Trace:
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.632173]  [<ffffffffa01dedcc>] nouveau_vm_map_sg+0xdc/0x150 [nouveau]
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.632235]  [<ffffffffa021ab81>] nouveau_vma_getmap.isra.14+0x61/0x90 [nouveau]
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.632295]  [<ffffffffa021ac2a>] nouveau_bo_move_m2mf.isra.15+0x7a/0x130 [nouveau]
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.632351]  [<ffffffffa021b530>] nouveau_bo_move+0xa0/0x430 [nouveau]
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.632391]  [<ffffffffa008ee9d>] ttm_bo_handle_move_mem+0x24d/0x5c0 [ttm]
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.632432]  [<ffffffffa008f8d9>] ? ttm_bo_mem_space+0x179/0x360 [ttm]
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.632475]  [<ffffffffa008fecf>] ttm_bo_move_buffer+0x11f/0x140 [ttm]
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.632517]  [<ffffffff810bf944>] ? tick_program_event+0x24/0x30
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.632558]  [<ffffffffa008ff7a>] ttm_bo_validate+0x8a/0x100 [ttm]
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.632612]  [<ffffffffa021bf3a>] nouveau_bo_pin+0xda/0x170 [nouveau]
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.632667]  [<ffffffffa023e42c>] nv50_crtc_swap_fbs.isra.12+0x2c/0xd0 [nouveau]
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.632725]  [<ffffffffa021c27c>] ? nouveau_bo_rd32+0x2c/0x30 [nouveau]
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.632782]  [<ffffffffa0240481>] nv50_crtc_mode_set+0x121/0x3f0 [nouveau]
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.632826]  [<ffffffffa010f02c>] drm_crtc_helper_set_mode+0x27c/0x450 [drm_kms_helper]
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.632877]  [<ffffffffa011067e>] drm_crtc_helper_set_config+0x99e/0xaf0 [drm_kms_helper]
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.632936]  [<ffffffffa0052f8d>] drm_mode_set_config_internal+0x5d/0xe0 [drm]
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.634614]  [<ffffffffa00559c7>] drm_mode_setcrtc+0xf7/0x650 [drm]
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.636343]  [<ffffffffa0226db0>] ? nouveau_user_framebuffer_create+0x60/0xb0 [nouveau]
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.638033]  [<ffffffff816e8902>] ? mutex_lock+0x12/0x2f
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.639735]  [<ffffffffa0046212>] drm_ioctl+0x532/0x660 [drm]
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.641378]  [<ffffffff811b8ba5>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x2e5/0x4d0
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.643044]  [<ffffffff811a91f1>] ? __sb_end_write+0x31/0x60
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.644726]  [<ffffffff811a6d82>] ? vfs_write+0x172/0x1e0
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.646494]  [<ffffffff811b8e11>] SyS_ioctl+0x81/0xa0
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.648122]  [<ffffffff816f521d>] system_call_fastpath+0x1a/0x1f
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.649646] Code: 45 d0 48 8d 04 d5 08 00 00 00 48 89 45 c0 41 8d 44 24 04 89 45 bc eb 0c 0f 1f 44 00 00 48 8b 45 b0 8b 70 30 48 8b 45 c8 4c 89 f7 <4a> 8b 14 38 48 c1 ea 08 49 89 d5 48 83 ca 03 49 83 cd 01 83 e6 
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.652856] RIP  [<ffffffffa01e0eb6>] nvc0_vm_map_sg+0x96/0x100 [nouveau]
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.654394]  RSP <ffff880230c4f5f0>
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.655842] CR2: 0000000000000000
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO pulseaudio[2507]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
Feb  9 23:55:15 daniel-LIFEBOOK-AH531-GFO kernel: [   74.666275] ---[ end trace fae09bf583a1a106 ]---
```

xorg.20.log (what does resizing framebuffer to 2390x768 mean? It's not my screen resolution):

```
[    74.441] reporting 5 6 34 244
[    74.461] reporting 5 6 34 244
[    74.467] reporting 5 6 34 244
[    74.517] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-1BCDDEFD4E35562D3483623A3498B96EFC960598.xkm
[    74.532] reporting 5 6 34 244
[    74.546] reporting 5 6 34 244
[    74.575] reporting 5 6 34 244
[    74.577] reporting 5 6 34 244
[    74.592] reporting 5 6 34 244
[    74.595] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "LGD", prod id 732
[    74.595] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    74.595] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   70.00  1366 1402 1450 1492  768 771 776 782 -hsync -vsync (46.9 kHz eP)
[    74.596] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "LGD", prod id 732
[    74.596] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    74.596] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   70.00  1366 1402 1450 1492  768 771 776 782 -hsync -vsync (46.9 kHz eP)
[    74.612] reporting 5 6 34 244
[    74.623] (II) intel(0): resizing framebuffer to 2390x768
[    74.623] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1366x768@60.0 on pipe 0 using LVDS1, position (0, 0), rotation normal
[    74.640] have a master to look out for
[    74.640] adjust shatters 0 2390
[    74.640] need to create shared pixmap 1
```

output of df

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6      148860244  34569704 106705824  25% /
none                   4         0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             4028988         4   4028984   1% /dev
tmpfs             808724      1232    807492   1% /run
none                5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             4043620       416   4043204   1% /run/shm
none              102400        36    102364   1% /run/user
/dev/sdb1      527771640 143074604 384697036  28% /media/sw/Volume
/dev/sdb2      201586656   4858500 186488108   3% /media/sw/LINPROG
```

Comment: what `df` gives you ? last time I encountered something like this it was because of very low disk space on home partition

Comment: There is enough space on any partition, I added the output to the question.

Comment: yes you're right, it worth a shot anyway.

Comment: If you create a third account with a different home dir (echo ~username), is the behavior the same?

Comment: same behaviour.

Comment: *maybe* you hit a bug in the `nouveau` drivers; could you try to proprietary `nvidia` drivers and see if the problem persists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks a lot like an issue with your graphics card driver (nouveau) crashing when loading the second desktop for some reason (I am no kernel expert so I can't explain why).

I'd suggestion either:

- Try a more recent kernel (you may need to build it yourself if there's none already available for Mint).
- If you don't mind using proprietary software, try installing the latest driver from Nvidia.

I also notice mentions to Intel in your Xorg.log, are you by chance using one of those hybrid graphics laptops? If so, you can also try blacklisting the nouveau module entirely and see if you have any issues using only the Intel driver for the integrated graphics and see if it helps.

Comment: Thx, I switched to the nvidia driver, this problem is gone but now I have some other minor issues. Yes, it's one of these hybrid graphic cards.